# Authenticate with Azure Management Libraries for .NET using Azure AD v2.0

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

Is there a way to use MSAL to get an access token that can be used in Azure Management Libraries? I have read [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md) and they don't mention it, but is it possible to use MSAL or ADAL to connect to Microsoft Graph, and then create a service principal using the [beta API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/serviceprincipal)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use MSAL to get an access token that can be used in
>   Azure Management Libraries

You cannot use MSAL to access Azure Management directly, Azure Management Lib need to get some other thing but not only the access token.Reference [1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md). [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/dotnet-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-dotnet).

> is it possible to use MSAL or ADAL to connect to Microsoft Graph, and
>   then create a service principal using the beta API?

Yes. You can get started with the [official sample](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) .The net project will use the MSAL by default.

More reference:
https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-v2-and-msal-from-dev-pov

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-management-libraries-for-net-generally-available-now/

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Adal-to-Msal